# How to create a new SBT project with LibGDX?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, libgdx, sbt

I want to create a new SBT project with LibGDX and use IntelliJ as my IDE. I have tried following these [instructions](https://github.com/sinistersnare/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-Scala) and, even though I completed the g8 setup process succesfully, I can't run the project through the SBT shell.

```
[IJ]> desktop/run
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: desktop
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: desktop (similar: test, skip, description)
[error] desktop/run
[error]        ^
[IJ]> run
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Nov 18, 2017 5:45:03 PM
[IJ]> baseDirectory
[info] C:\Users\<MyName>\IdeaProjects\MyProject
[IJ]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, when I ran the g8 template it created a folder with my project name automatically - so my folder structure looked like C:\Users\MyName\IdeaProject\MyProject\myproject. I ran sbt in C:\Users\MyName\IdeaProject\MyProject which created an incorrect sbt build when I should have run it in C:\Users\MyName\IdeaProject\MyProject\myproject.

Additionally, the ios module was failing but I am not going to target ios so I removed the roboscala plugin and the ios variables from the build.scala and plugins.sbt.